# SendFile pass extra parameters

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

i am using sendfile function.

i  need username in myhtml.html

Can we pass username in below function

```
var HTMLLOCATION = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../html');

res.sendfile(HTMLLOCATION + '/myhtml.html');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be achived by keeping your HTML in string replace patter.
Follow something like this
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_format_format